# $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{C_R} \frac{6z^6 + 5z^5}{z^6 + z^5 + 10}dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am solving the following problem:
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{C_R} \frac{6z^6 + 5z^5}{z^6 + z^5 + 10}dz,$$
where $C_R=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=R  \}$ for $R>0$.

The only one idea I have is to use the Residue theorem.

But I couldn't apply the theorem to the above problem.

Comment: The problem is NOT to find the integral but to find the limit as R goes to 0.  For R **very, very** large, the highest power will dominate.

Comment: I think user is right. If you had to evaluate the integral then you'd have a very, very tough problem as that denominator polynomial's roots seem to be very hard to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the residue theorem. The function in every circle is holomirphic except for the poles, and given some big $R>0$ all the poles of the function are contained in the circle, so that is the limit.

Comment: Actually, i considered it. But how i know the zeros of the equation $z^6+z^5+10=0$. In order to apply residue theorem, we should know the zeros. Am i wrong...?

Comment: Ok I didn't thought you were interested in the exact numerical value. Because yes, you need the zeros, but from the fundamental theorem of algebra there are only six of them, so the integral is the sum of those six. (Sorry I am usually more concerned with existence)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Try writing $z= R e^{it} $ for $0\leq t < 2\pi$. Then $dz = i R e^{it}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(z) = z^{6} + z^{5} + 10$. Then the integral is same as 
$$
\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{C_{R}} \frac{z p'(z)}{p(z)}dz. 
$$
If we put $p(z) = \prod_{i=1}^{6} (z-\alpha_{i})$, then 
$$
\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = \sum_{i=1}^{6}\frac{1}{z-\alpha_{i}}
$$
and so 
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{C_{R}} z\sum_{i=1}^{6}\frac{1}{z-\alpha_{i}}dz = 2\pi i \sum_{i=1}^{6}\alpha_{i} = -2\pi i 
$$
by Vieta's formula.

Comment: Thank you! The second equation is crucial! Good!! (Actually, i couldn't move forward from the first equation.)